# SQLalchemy request is too slow

Tags: python-3.x, performance, sqlalchemy

I'm having some difficulty understanding why one of my SQL request displayed below is taking me way too much time when it shouldn't.
This SQL request take me about 400ms when the database only have 2500 lines.
As you can see also in the code below, the model doesn't have a lot of complicated stuff. The only thing that could make it difficult is the "emoji" field which is a litteral emoji in the database.

I've tried to do the same request with the mysql_connector library and it took me 15ms.

I've linked some files that displays the cProfile results.

[image: cProfile for mysql_connector (no ORM)]

[image: cProfile for sqlalchemy request (with ORM)]

Also below, the source code for sqlalchemy test:

```py
import cProfile
from isomodels.models import NotableAccount
from sqlalchemy import URL, create_engine, select
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
if __name__ == '__main__':
    connection_string = URL.create(drivername="mysql+mysqlconnector",
                                   username="root",
                                   password="xxxxx",
                                   host="localhost",
                                   port=3306,
                                   database="xxxxxx")
    engine = create_engine(connection_string)
    session = Session(engine)
    pr2 = cProfile.Profile()
    pr2.enable()
    stmt = select(NotableAccount)
    accounts = session.scalars(stmt).all()
    pr2.disable()
    pr2.print_stats(sort="cumtime")
    session.close()

class NotableAccount(Base):
    __tablename__ = "notableaccount"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    twitter_id: Mapped[str]
    handle: Mapped[str]
    username: Mapped[str]
    ranking: Mapped[int]
    emoji: Mapped[Optional[str]]
    category_id: Mapped[int]
```

Any idea what could cause that and how could I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: "As you can see also in the code below, the model doesn't have a lot of complicated stuff." -> the code for the model has not been provided

Comment: @snakecharmerb my bad, just added it

Comment: So the raw DBAPI method results in 5K function calls while the ORM method results in over 100K function calls. Clearly SQLAlchemy is doing more than just retrieve the rows and dump them into (what is essentially) a list of tuples.

Comment: I tried with 3000 rows and the SQLA time was ~5x the mysql connector time.

Comment: How is the difference if you directly use core? `connection = engine.connect()` and `connection.execute(NotableAccount.__table__.select()).fetchall()`

Comment: @python_user If i do that, it is waaay faster (84ms) which is good. But with that solution i'm losing the ORM. Would that mean that the issue is located in the conversion/creation of objects?

Comment: yes, pretty much what @GordThompson alluded to, one of the reasons some people claim "ORMs are slow" is because of this, the deserialization to python object is slow. Plus the session does some stuff so you can get "unit of work" pattern going

Comment: @python_user Thanks for your remarks but the request you've given me above still cast type to int, str, ... Why casting Row to the NotableAccount adds 10x the time?

Comment: I am guessing here as I am not aware of neither SQLA nor python internals, that being said, int / str / tuples etc are implemented in C and `Row` probably is cython? These are probably faster compared to a full blown "custom type" (sqla models) implemented in python. Also to emphasize on what I mentioned, ORM does more than just converting to SQLA models like maintaining relationships and identity map to name a few

Comment: FWIW, my own test (2500 rows, SQLA 2.0.29, local MySQL db) are much closer to what @snakecharmerb reported: ORM time was ~4x raw DBAPI time, not 27x as stated in the question.